# Why is Laravel Socialite not able to find the "isNewUser" method?

Tags: laravel, twitter, laravel-5.5, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I've set up Laravel 5.5 and Socialite 3.1, but after signing in to Twitter and returning to my app, I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::isNewUser()
```

I can't seem to find any information about this particular method or what is causing this error. How do I get around it?

After downgrading to Socialite to 3.0.12, I was getting a blank page at the callback instead of the error above. This was due to a missing user creation implementation, which I wrote and got it all working in the end. However, I'd like to know what the error above means.

Comment: It looks like a bug; it had gotten renamed to shouldBypassCache in all places except the TwitterProvider class. I've submitted a pull request to address it: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/278

Comment: I have this issue either.

Comment: The fix got merged in this morning, so you should be set to run `composer update` and get the 3.1.1 tag

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this Code, Please update your composer.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/One/TwitterProvider.php